# Creation of triggers and effect on the table using the temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to create a trigger in SQL Server 2012 by following the below steps :

1. When changing column either `jandata`, `febdata`, `janarea` or `febarea` in table called `project` (`pkid,prjid,jandata,febdata,janarea,febarea`)
2. Then I need to perform certain calculations which I can perform and then store new data in a temporary table
3. I need to check in items table if the itemid exists then i need to update the column values in the table else i need to insert the values

So right now I am stuck with the first step how to create a trigger and insert values in temporary table

I used this code

```
CREATE TRIGGER sysgenitemsvalue 
UPDATE ON project
BEGIN
    create table #temp
    (
    pkid int,
    JANORG  int,
    FEBORG  int,
    ORGID int,
    PROJID int,
    BUDGETYEAR int
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp(pkid, JANORG, FEBORG, ORGID, PROJID, BUDGETYEAR)
        SELECT 
            v.pkid, 
            CASE 
                WHEN v.JANORG <> '0' THEN v.JANORG 
                WHEN v.JANAREA <> '0' THEN v.JANAREA 
                ELSE p.JANORG 
            END "JANORG",
            CASE 
                WHEN v.FEBORG <> '0' THEN v.FEBORG 
                WHEN v.FEBAREA <> '0' THEN v.FEBAREA 
                ELSE p.FEBORG 
            END  "FEBORG",
            o.org_id, o.pt_id, o.budgetyear
        FROM 
            project v, proj p, org o
        WHERE 
            o.pkid = v.orgpt_id 
            AND o.pt_id = p.projid 
            AND p.orgid = o.org_id 
            AND p.budgetyear = o.budgetyear
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense here. Why do you need a temp table? Also, your table structure sounds like it could use some normalization. If you need to know how to create a trigger in sql server you would do yourself a great favor by using a search engine. Here is an example. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+create+trigger&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion and i was not aware of this search engine I need a temp table so that i can compare the data and update accordingly and i cannot do the normalization that is why i am working on triggers. I am unable to create a temporary table with certain values using triggers

Comment: Not how being unable to normalize your tables forces you to use triggers. They are completely unrelated. Regardless, I doubt you really need temp tables. You already have the inserted and deleted virtual tables at your fingertips. Perhaps if you can explain what you are trying to do we can help you find a solution that is efficient.

Comment: When project table value gets changed i need to perform certain calculations and then i would need to store them in other table if the values exists i need to update else insert so what i ma trying to do is stroe some data in temporary table and do the calculations and then i am trying to check in other table

Comment: You don't need a temp table for this. It is still 100% unclear what you are trying to do. You might be able to use a cte or even just this query but a temp table here is likely overkill. Also you really need to start using the ANSI-92 style joins instead of this older version. It has been around for almost 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What is wrong with your current script?   are you getting an error message?

Comment: See i want to pick values from project table and then do certain calculations on basis of 1 more query and then after calculating them i need to store values in 3rd table

Comment: Look into the [create trigger documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). Read it then read it again. Make sure you understand what the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables mean in the context of triggers. Then rethink your trigger.

Comment: The trigger is created successfully but when i try to see the values inserted in temporary table it says the temporary table doesnt exist